# curl API PHP using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to get wikipedia api using curl PHP with geonames. But it seems to be something wrong in the connection between the php file and the script. I have tried the url with hard coded values in the PHP and it works however if I tried to concatenate using $_REQUEST the url doesnt work is like the parameter is missing. I hard coded the data in the ajax just to check if is working at the moment but once is working it should getting the information from the form. The code looks like this:

```js
$("#wikiSearch").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/requests.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: "london",
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log("success");
            console.log(result);

        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            // console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            // console.log( "Status: " + status );
            // console.dir( xhr );
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>APIS examples</title>
        <meta name="author" content="GeoNames APIs">
        <meta name="description" content="APIS example">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">
        <!--<link href="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>-->


        
        

    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Search in Wikipedia" name="input">
                <br>
                <button type="submit" id="wikiSearch">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/script.js"></script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

```js
<?php

    
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?q='. $_REQUEST["q"] . '&maxRows=10&username=xxxxx';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    //$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    //print_r($result);
    //var_dump($_POST);

    
    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);
    
    


    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this related to Javascript, or solely to PHP?

Comment: For one thing, you're not preventing the actual submission of the form, so I'd expect that your page reloads when you click the button?

Comment: For this kind of debugging the browser console Network tab is essential, check that the URL it went to is correct, that the payload is correct, and look at the response/error that your php sent back.  Beware of passing params directly from user input like that, if the user puts london&maxRows=1000 in the input field what happens to your api call.

Comment: I have been running the PHP file in the browser to look for mistakes and check if the data is receive before moving on with the form. I tried to run the url in PHP with hard coded parameters and it is working. I believe the problem is n the $_REQUEST or the ajax.

Comment: Refer to my previous comment. If the page is reloaded, then the AJAX call has no effect on it.

Comment: why use options specifically for SSL connections when using a url with `http` rather than `https` scheme?

Comment: submiting the form reloads the page but I am not receiving any data from the request anyway. I also commented the SSL connections for http

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: q in C:\MAMP\htdocs\apis\libs\php\requests.php on line 9
{"status":{"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"mission saved","returnedIn":"1612645.1223916 ms"},"data":{"geonames":[]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your original code but modified to a single page with a simple `Fetch` call and NO curl - it might be useful to help you diagnose your issue. This works "as-is"

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['q'] ) ){
        
        $st = microtime(true) / 1000;
        
        $username='geronimo';
        $rows=10;
        
        $url=sprintf(
            'http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?q=%s&maxRows=%d&username=%s',
            $_POST['q'],
            $rows,
            $username
        );
        $json=file_get_contents( $url );
        $output=['status' => [
            'code'          =>  200,
            'name'          =>  'ok',
            'description'   =>  'mission_saved',
            'returnedIn'    =>  ( microtime(true) - $st ) / 1000 . " ms",
            'data'          =>  json_decode($json)
        ]];
        exit( json_encode($output) );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>APIS examples</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Search in Wikipedia" name="input">
                <br />
                <button type="submit" id="wikiSearch">Search</button>
            </form>
            <output></output>
            
            
            <script>
                document.getElementById('wikiSearch').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.append('q',e.target.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="input"]').value);
                        
                        
                    fetch( location.href, { method:'post',body:fd })
                        .then( r=>r.json() )
                        .then( json=>{
                            console.log(json);
                            document.querySelector('output').textContent=JSON.stringify(json)
                        })                  
                    
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could tweak your PHP to include some of the same logic ( to test that the `q` is present )

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['q'] ) ){
    
        $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

        $url='http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?q='. $_POST['q'] . '&maxRows=10&username=geronimo';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $decode = json_decode($result,true);
        
        $output['status']['code'] = "200";
        $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
        $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
        $output['data'] = $decode;
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        exit( json_encode( $output ) ); 
    }
?>
```

But your AJAX function needs to be prevented from allowing the `button` to actually SUBMIT the form as it would try to do normally - hence using `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("#wikiSearch").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/requests.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: "london",
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log("success");
            console.log(result);

        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            // console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            // console.log( "Status: " + status );
            // console.dir( xhr );
        }
    }); 
});
```